# how to stop android things app on raspberry pi 3 and start another activity

Tags: android, android-things

I develop my first android things app from the "https://developer.android.com/things/training/first-device/peripherals.html#handle_button_events" site. And deploy it on raspberry pi 3 (booted up on version 4.1).

The easily deploy on raspberry pi 3 and give me blinking Led too.

But now i don't know how to stop it, and make changes or start some other project.

It contineously blinking and i don't know how to stop it.

In my android studio when i press the start button, then it display the connected devices menu in which it says that raspberry pi is offline.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FhLg.png)

Comment: The reason why it says OFFLINE is probably due to the fact that your raspberry pi have does not allow your machine to debug it's applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have set the application as your default start-up application. Thus it will load as soon as you switch on your Android Thing device. To overcome this one solution is to simply uninstall the current package remotely using command:

adb uninstall pkg-name

or by using below command and manually uninstalling it:

adb shell am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS

If you are in debugging phase, better goto manifest file and replace following lines :

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

with:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Doing this will prevent from making the application as your default boot up application

Update 1: IOT_LAUNCHER is deprecated and should be replaced with HOME

Answer (score 3):

You can use **adb** for many things, lets see few adb commands which will help you with your android application development and testing.

Assume that your device has **IP** 10.10.0.123

**Connecting to your device through adb**

```
$ adb connect 10.10.0.123:5555
```

**Checking your available list of connected devices**

```
$ adb devices
```

the above command gives output

```
List of devices attached 
10.10.0.123:5555    device
```

**Installing application can be done by using following command**

```
$ adb -s 10.10.0.123:5555 install <path to your apk file>
```

example:

```
$ adb -s 10.10.0.123:5555 install /home/shahbaz/Android-apps/example.apk
```

Installation takes time depending on size of the application, so have patience

The above installation command outputs

```
502 KB/s (15896167 bytes in 30.870s)
Success
```

**Uninstall Application**

For this you must know the package name of application

```
$ adb uninstall com.example.app
```

**Launching Application**
First connect to the device then run following command

```
$ adb shell 'am start $(cmd package resolve-activity --brief <package-name> | tail -n 1)'
```

example

```
 $ adb shell 'am start $(cmd package resolve-activity --brief com.example.app | tail -n 1)'
```

Output of this command is some what like this

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.app/.SpalshScreen }
```

**Closing the Launched Application**

```
$ adb shell am force-stop <package-name>
```

example

```
$ adb shell am force-stop com.example.app
```

You can further check the man page of **adb** for other operations.

Hope this may help !

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by executing the 'adb kill-server' command on CMD. And then reconnect the raspberry pi 3. Thus, the offline tag is removed from the raspberry pi 3 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Only one app is "auto started" by the Android Things OS. Therefore your old app keeps being started.

You have to uninstall old apps to ensure your new app is the one started. You can uninstall it with

`adb uninstall your.package.name`

Alternatively, if you have a few old apps installed you can use this script file:

https://gist.github.com/blundell/7c0c3bb17898b28fe8122b0dc230af50

To uninstall them all (without needed to know the package name!)

[image]

---

If your Rasp Pi is seen as offline you can power cycle it (turn it off an on again). :-)

---

Script has now been updated to look for:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

which replaces `IOT_LAUNCHER` in the latest version (DP8)

Answer (score 0):

In android things you can use only one application at a time,so use `adb uninstall <installed-app-pkg-name>` and then start installing your another project into Raspberry Pi 3. Also remove the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>` so your app will not start on boot up.

Currently this `<category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>` has been replaced with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>` in android things stable release 1.0.

Hope this will help you.